# JToolBar - JButton - Image not showing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, embedded-resource, jtoolbar

My main dialog has gotten so cluttered with buttons.  I thought it would be pretty cool to just add a tool bar with some of the buttons to the dialog.

I am currently using a image in a application toolbar to start my application.  It is in Plugin.xml code

```
 icon="icons/ediOrb.png"
```

So in my Dialog I am trying to use the same icon for my refreshButton

```
JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
refreshButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("icons/ediOrb.png"));
refreshButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        refreshTable();
     }
  });
  toolbar.add(refreshButton);
  centerPanel = new JPanel();
  centerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(centerPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
  centerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(850, 450));
  centerPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5, 0)));
  centerPanel.add(currentPanel);
  centerPanel.add(selectionsPanel);
  centerPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
  centerPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 2)));
  centerPanel.add(buttonPanel);
  getContentPane().add(toolbar,BorderLayout.PAGE_START );
  getContentPane().add(centerPanel);
```

There is no image showing for the button.  It only shows a tiny spot.  It is not throwing any errors, just does not show the image.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you certain the image can be found at that location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.  In Netbeans I had to go to:

```
Run | Set Project Configuration | customize --
```

Then add the Working Directory path that contained my project and the icons.
I'm not sure how to do this in a different IDE but my Icons showed up after this fix.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
refreshButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/ediOrb.png")).getImage()));
```

Comment: Robin posted a comment to your question. Can you clarify on that? Or tell us more about the location of your image files

Comment: Try getClass().getResource("/icons/ediOrb.png") instead

Answer (score 0):

If your icons folder is under src folder.

```
JButton refreshButton = new JButton();
  try {
    Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("icons/ediOrb.png"));
    refreshButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
  } catch (IOException ex) {
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
refreshButton .setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("icons/ediOrb.png")));
```

However, make sure the image is not too large(happened to me once) + the path is correct. Test it with giving the COMPLETE path.